# Insert into two dependent tables in mysql using sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, sequelize.js

I have been trying to insert the values in two dependent tables question and option where option has a column named question_id, which is a foreign key.

I have this mysql query, which I want to convert into sequelize

```
INSERT INTO question(question_text, level_id, age_group_id, status,createdAt,updatedAt)
VALUES ('this is the question', 1, 2, 1,now(), now());
INSERT INTO option(question_id, answer_text, answer_is_correct, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),"this is the option", 1,now(), now())
```

Comment: Should `user_detail` table be changed to `option`? Didn't see `question` and `option` table in your SQL

Comment: sorry its not user_detail it is option

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Creating with associations](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#creating-with-associations) to do this after defined the models.

E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, Op } from 'sequelize';

class Question extends Model {}
Question.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    question_text: DataTypes.STRING,
    level_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    age_group_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'question', timestamps: true },
);

class Option extends Model {}
Option.init(
  {
    question_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    answer_text: DataTypes.STRING,
    answer_is_correct: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'option', timestamps: true },
);

Question.hasMany(Option, { foreignKey: 'question_id', sourceKey: 'id' });
Option.belongsTo(Question, { foreignKey: 'question_id', targetKey: 'id' });

(async function test() {
  try {
    // create tables
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // test
    await Question.create(
      {
        question_text: 'this is the question',
        level_id: 1,
        age_group_id: 2,
        status: 1,
        options: [
          {
            answer_text: 'this is the option',
            answer_is_correct: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      { include: [Option] },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution results:

```sh
...
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "question" ("id","question_text","level_id","age_group_id","status","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "option" ("question_id","answer_text","answer_is_correct","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *;
```

Check the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "question";
 id |    question_text     | level_id | age_group_id | status |         createdAt          |         updatedAt
----+----------------------+----------+--------------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | this is the question |        1 |            2 |      1 | 2020-04-15 04:13:39.311+00 | 2020-04-15 04:13:39.311+00
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "option";
 question_id |    answer_text     | answer_is_correct |         createdAt          |         updatedAt
-------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
           1 | this is the option |                 1 | 2020-04-15 04:13:39.332+00 | 2020-04-15 04:13:39.332+00
(1 row)
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/60202025